# Connecting Wall

Tags: pattern, wordplay, connect-wall

These sixteen words can be divided into four groups of four, each of which has something in common. What are the groups, and what are the connections between them?

[image: 4 by 4 table. First row: Cafe, Justice, Willis, Strength. Second Row: Bone, Quebec, Life, Cheddar. Third Row: Naive, Scratch, Death, Fifths. Fourth Row: Hell, Temperance, Angstrom, Bread.]
(Inspired by the British TV show *Only Connect*, which I have been obsessively watching for the past few days.)

Comment: Another Connect Wall: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/

Comment: @f'': Didn't even realize there already was one here! Yeah, that one's probably a lot harder than mine.

Comment: Nice puzzle! Let me know how I did :D.

Comment: This puzzle is fun, which is really the most important criterion.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was talking about when I said British television was better than American television: they have puzzles!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dan Russell got two categories:

> Slang for money: Cheddar, Scratch, Bread, Bone.

and

> Tarot cards: Strength, Justice, Temperance, Death.

The other two categories are:

> Words written with accents: Café, Québec, Naïve, Ångström.

and

> Circles: Circle of Willis, Circle(s) of Hell, Circle of Fifths, Circle of Life.

Comment: And that's correct! Fairly easy, but hopefully fun.

Comment: Ah, was just about to add the first of your two additions. Was nowhere near the second, though.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps one category is

> **Slang for Money** which would include **Cheddar**, **Scratch**, **Bread**, and **Bone**

Another could be

> **Tarot Cards** which would include **Strength**, **Temperance**, **Justice**, and **Death**

Working on the others...

Comment: Those two are correct, and f'' finished it off!

Answer (score 3):

I think I've got this one.

**Canada**

> The **Willis** Towers Watson company (a global multinational risk management, insurance brokerage and advisory company with offices in the **Quebec** city of Montreal) is right across the street from the Premium By Presse **Cafe** (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1gH2.jpg)), which serves many food dishes including classic sandwiches (which include **bread** of course). [View their menu.](http://www.pressecafe.com/en/menus/presswiches-and-classic-sandwiches/)

**Life or Death**

> When **death** begins, **life** ends; certain dead people (those who lack **temperance**) often go to **hell**.

**Knowledge**

> **Naive** people (either those whose minds lack **strength** or those who don’t help to bring **justice** to the world) never possess the knowledge of what an **angstrom** is.

**Dinner**

> A hunk of **Cheddar** cheese can be cut into **fifths**, **scratched** with a knife blade (which makes it melt faster), and finally melted onto a **bone**less chicken thigh for a delicious dinner.

Comment: ...Sorry, but not even close. Each category can be described with very few words - I'd say 3 or 4, maximum. They're not subjective, either - once you get it, you'll know that you've gotten it. (And they're *categories*, not *stories*.)

Comment: (Also, note the [wordplay] tag.)

Comment: @Deusovi Yeah :|. You have to admit my first one is pretty convincing though...

Comment: No, not particularly... See Dan's recent answer for an example of what a category might look like.