# Another Only Connect Wall

Tags: pattern, wordplay, knowledge, connect-wall

This is an Only Connect Wall, like the several ([some](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/only-connect-connect-wall-1) [examples](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/an-only-connect-wall) [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38768/connecting-wall)) that have been posted here in the past.

The goal is to divide the 16 words below into 4 thematically connected groupings of 4 words each.

Image version (credit to @Mithrandir for making this image for me):

[image: wall]

Text version:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    CRASH     |ACKNOWLEDGMENT|   SAVIOUR    |   OMISSION   |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| CONGREGATION |    SAINT     |    CHEQUE    |     BILL     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   OUTCOME    |     GREY     |  INTRUSION   |   GAMBLER    |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|     RAM      |    MURDER    |    BROWN     | CONFIRMATION |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've been lurking on Puzzling.SE and enjoying the puzzles for a little while now but this is my first shot at actually using the site as a user so I apologize in advance for any breaches of etiquette.

I intended for this one to be at least as difficult as the average wall, but it seems puzzle creators here are regularly surprised by how quickly their creations get solved, so I'll withhold any hints for the time being. If it doesn't get solved quickly I can post some hints and/or confirm correct groupings.

**EDIT:**

Correctly identified groupings so far:

Group 1

> Bill, Ram, Brown, Saint ([credit to Going hamateur](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42443/another-only-connect-wall/42444#42444))

Group 2

> Intrusion, Murder, Congregation, Crash ([credit to Going hamateur](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42443/another-only-connect-wall/42444#42444))

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: Want me to create an image for you? It's cooler with one :P

Comment: @Mithrandir Sure thing, that'd be great. I'm at work and lack the tools to do so.

Comment: How's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTP8.png)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Groups are as follows:

Group 1: Thanks @Going Hamature

> Intrusion, Murder, Congregation, Crash: Collective nouns for animals; an Intrusion of Cockroaches, a Murder or Crows, a Congregation of Alligators, a Crash of Rhinos

Group 2: @Going Hamature got this first, but I also came up with it independently

> Bill, Ram, Brown, Saint: NFL teams; Buffalo Bills, Los Angeles Rams, Cleveland Browns, New Orleans Saints

Group 3:

> Gambler, Confirmation, Outcome, Omission: These all represent various types of cognitive bias. Gambler's Fallacy, Confirmation Bias, Outcome Bias, and Omission Bias.

And Group 4:

> Grey, Cheque, Saviour, Acknowledgment: Words spelt differently in American and British English, Grey/Gray, Cheque/Check, Saviour/Savior, Acknowledgment/Acknowledgement

Comment: This is correct! Would you mind posting another answer with just the 4 groupings and explanations for each of them so I can mark it as the correct answer? Not sure what the protocol is here so if there's a better way I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @rollingthunder updated answer to have only the correct stuff, the first guess is still there in the edit history, if anyone cares.

Answer (score 4):

First grouping possiblity:

> Bill, Ram, Brown, Saint
>  football teams minus an S (probably in honor of yesterdays football starting)

Second grouping:

> Intrusion murder congregation crash
>  Groups of things: Murder of crows, intrusion of cockroaches, crash of rhinos, congregation of alligators (credit to dcfyj for alligators not church people)

Third grouping:

> Acknowledgement omission confirmation cheque
>  Bank stuff that happens

Fourth grouping:

> Outcome Saviour Gambler Grey
>  okay I am not that sure of group 3.

Remaining words:

> outcome acknowledgement omission confirmation saviour cheque gambler grey

Comment: Alligators group in congregations, as well.