# Animal connect wall

Tags: connect-wall, animals

I made a connect wall about animals:

```
tarsier         ascidian           aye-aye       

caecilian       diplocaulus        bird

marsupial       amphiuma           hagfish

fish            lamprey            mammals
```

There are 4 categories containing 3 words each.

Category 1 hint:

> A type of cap and gown

Category 2 hint:

> any animal with a backbone

Comment: Would you consider giving a few hints? (but don't give it all away)

Comment: @hat one clue given and bounty started!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Hat got 1 group correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, my answer was getting long. If you want to see my other tries, look at the edit history. Here goes another shot!

> nocturnal animals - **marsupial, tarsier, aye-aye**. chordates - **hagfish, lamprey, ascidian**. amphibians - **diplocaulus, amphiuma, caecilian**. vertebrates - **birds, fish, mammals**.

Now technically my second and fourth classes could switch some, since (

> Despite not having a backbone, hagfish are considered vertebrates. Lampreys are vertebrates as well, if I remember correctly.

)

Comment: how was my new try?

Comment: still a bit of.

Comment: ahhhhhh!!! Now we're talking. Though I still have no clue how the cap and gown is related lol

Comment: 3/4 the other category is correct just hasn’t got the right name

Comment: close, chordates, and nocturnal animals are correct. The other groups have the wrong names and maybe animals. Hint: you were right before the edit

Comment: I mean the name of the group nocturnal animals and chordates are correct

Comment: wait I was right before which edit?

Comment: The name nocturnal animals and chordates are correct

Comment: nocturnal animals, chordates **phibi*** v***ebr****

Comment: lol it bolded your "++phibi+++". I was so confused. So wait, my first try had 2 category names right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: How can "marsupial" be categorised as an animal, or nocturnal? It's an infraclass of animals with a very broad range of behaviours.

Comment: Well, the numbat is the only marsupial active during the day, so I figured that "marsupial" at large could fit here. He also said that the nocturnal category name was correct, and I didn't see anything else that fit.

Comment: @Brandon_J  Congrats!

Comment: I did it???!?!?! yay!

Comment: Good puzzle, btw. and thanks for all those hints haha

Comment: @Brandon_J Kangaroos, koalas, wallabies, wombats, etc, etc, are all diurnal marsupials.

Comment: OK. Looked at https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/animals/marsupial (first google result for my search) and saw "The numbat is the only marsupial active during the day—all others are nocturnal or crepuscular." Maybe they meant to say that it was the only one active **only** during the day. My bad, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think it’s:

> tarsier, aye-aye, hagfish, lamprey: these are common name species of animals

Then:

> Ascidian, caecilian, diplocaulus, amphiuma: these are Latin classifications of animals

And finally:

> Bird, marsupial, fish, mammals: these are common names of animal classes

Comment: Nice try! It is 4 groups of 3 and they are all a bit off

Answer (score 2):

An attempt, most likely some wrong:

1. > Caecilians, diplocaulus and amphiuma are all groups of amphibians
2. > Ascidian, hagfish, lamprey are all sea creatures (two fish and a sea squirt)
3. > Aye-aye and tarsier are both lemurs, and both mammals
4. > I would have said *bird, mammal, fish* here, as these are the major divisions, however the two animals in point three are **not** marsupials, so that is the only word left

Comment: Nice try! Not quite though

Comment: +1 for getting 1 group correct

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Thanks. I wonder which one...

Comment: I guess group 1 is the correct one