# Unscramble the words and find the odd one out

Tags: no-computers, odd-one-out

Unscramble these words:

> noacb
>
> olve
>
> aukccpe

Which is the odd one out? There are several possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution:

> *aukccpe* can be split into two words: *cup* and *cake*

> *noacb* can be split into two words: *cab* and *on*

> *olve* cannot be split into two words, so it is the odd one out.

Answer (score 1):

They are

> Bacon
> love
> cupcake

These are

> Anagrams of the words.

This means that

> Love is the odd one out because it is not a food, and cupcake has two words in it(cup and cake), and bacon has a homophone of baking?

Oh and I didn't use my computer :)

Comment: Good so far! What other possible solutions are there?

Comment: Thanks for editing! There is another solution for the odd one out though

Comment: Just wondering, how many odd ones are there? :) @DManokhin

Comment: Two solutions I think. So two words are the odd ones out in two different scenarios

Comment: You can also try https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77785/animal-connect-wall

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

> vole instead of love
>  Still probably the odd one out, in that you generally don't eat it.
>  The cupcake is also not an animal (part).

Comment: Cool. Still isn’t the full solution I’m looking for