# A fun riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Animals have been here
>
> So have plants
>
> An object with an internal
> combustion engine has visited
>
> So has something with four magnetometers

What am I?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton There are 15 characters in the first one and 11 in the second, so probably not(?).

Comment: anagram? or dissecting the same word, maybe?

Comment: can @DManokhin pls specify? thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Basically you need to try and fill in the word as a little challenge

Comment: but that would be too broad... it may likely get closed... consider giving it away?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton ok edited

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Solved it yet? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the edit it looks suspiciously like

> Space

Animals and plants have been

> to space

and so have many

> rockets (internal combustion engine).

There are

> cubesat (nano-satellite) parts which carry four magnetometers see [here](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4082&context=smallsat)

Comment: Well done! Your variant has correct

Comment: Thank you. I would never have guessed the blanks in your last version. I was just thinking... maybe you could have placed some guiding hints before filling in the blanks. Unfortunately it's too late now.

Comment: I'll try for my next puzzle. You could have a go at this: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77785/animal-connect-wall

Comment: By the way, there are several classifications for internal combustion engines: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine

Comment: @DManokhin: I will have a go at that one tomorrow, it's getting late now. It looks cool.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for:

> Space

Animals and plants

> have been to space

And

> Elon Musk's Tesla Roadster (internal combustion engine)

And

> Voyager 1 has four magnetometers