# My Lovely Connect Wall

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected words.
Additionally, each of the four groups can be represented by a single group-word.
Finally, the four group-words are connected by a single five-letter word.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BALLET | BRAIN | BRIE | BUTTER |
| CANDLE | JELLY | SON | FIRE |
| WEED | HOUSE | ELEVATOR | SICK |
| MONK | MAY | LION | WILL |

**Can you identify the four groups and the associated group-words?**
**What is the five letter word that links the group-words together?**

Comment: The words 'My Lovely [noun]' are so indelibly linked to the ultimate answer Stiv came to that it was almost easier to start there and work backwards for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a tricky one! Some of the words could fit into many categories, but I think the final categorisation yielding four groups of four is:

> **Group 1: SEA**
>
>  - Sea**WEED**
>  - Sea**SON**
>  - Sea**LION**
>  - Sea**SICK**
>
>  **Group 2: FLY**
>
>  - **HOUSE**fly
>  - **MAY**fly
>  - **BRIE**fly
>  - **BUTTER**fly
>
>  **Group 3: SHOE(S)**
>
>  - [**JELLY** shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelly_shoes)
>  - [**MONK** shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk_shoe)
>  - **BALLET** shoe
>  - [**ELEVATOR** shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_shoe)
>
>  **Group 4: POWER**
>
>  - **CANDLE**power
>  - **BRAIN**power
>  - **WILL**power
>  - **FIRE**power

The connection between these four categories is then:

> **HORSE** (SEAHORSE, HORSEFLY, HORSESHOE, HORSEPOWER)

As for the title:

> It's a reference to [one of the finest songs ever created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzYzVMcgWhg), instantly recognisable to all *Father Ted* fans!

Comment: Nice work! I had your 1 and 2 plus jellyfish, monkfish, lionfish, candlefish & house music, ballet music, elevator music... The only thing remaining would have been to find out what on Earth "will music" is!

Comment: @Jafe Thanks :) And yes, that's exactly what I meant about so many categories! I think hexomino did really well to put so many red herrings in this one. Even once you find the four correct categories, FIRE, MONK and HOUSE can all fit in at least two of them, and finding which one they're needed in is key!

Comment: +1 just for that iconic song - how they did not win Eurovision I will never know :P

Comment: All perfect, well done!