# Like pie and buttermilk

Tags: connect-wall

The set of sixteen words below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four words that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities. You'll find that the four commonalities have, themselves, something in common.

ART, BAND, BEE, BLOUSE, BRIDGE, CHANGE, COAT, COPING, HACK, LEG, LION, LOCH, PINAFORE, SWEATER, TABLE, WOOD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the four partitions are:

One:

> BLOUSE, COAT, PINAFORE, SWEATER -> CLOTHES

Two:

> BAND, COPING, HACK, TABLE -> _ SAW

Three:

> BEE, CHANGE, LION, LOCH -> SEA _

Four:

> ART, BRIDGE, LEG, WOOD -> _WORK

The commonality between the categories is:

> CLOTHES, SAW, SEA, WORK -> _ HORSE

The title:

> Pie and Buttermilk were horse film stars in the mid 20th century.

Comment: Not _exactly_ what I had in mind (and I think intended solution works better. Specifically, rot13(gerfgyr neg) doesn't seem to be a thing). But close. In particular, your final answer is correct — but what does it have to do with the puzzle title?

Comment: @msh210 We must have had similar ideas: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98588/my-lovely-connect-wall

Comment: Got it...will try to refine. Neat puzzle!

Comment: @hexomino I'd even seen that (though since forgotten it). Sorry.

Comment: @msh210 No need to apologise, I just thought it interesting that we aimed for the same connection.

Comment: @msh210: Are you thinking rot13(uvtu) instead of rot13(gerfgyr)? Given how generic it is as a term, I feel like there's no strong link, but there's also no weak link like rot13(gerfgyr neg).

Comment: No, @JeremyDover.

Comment: How about rot13(JBBQRA)? Works well for the theme, LEG and TABLE. Possibly ART and BRIDGE too?

Comment: That's not it, but it prompted me to think the right way...thanks @Stiv!!!

Comment: No, @Stiv, that's one of the words given.